# Can't push new heads - fail to see how they would be created

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm fairly new to version control in teams. So far I've mostly used it solo.

I've read that the following workflow is recommended:

> Commit locally, pull master, merge master into my branch, merge my
>   branch into master, push. Several times a week or even day

So that's what I tried to do. However, when I was done with my feature, and tried to push, tortoise hg told me, that this would create new remote heads.

hg help push tells me about two options:

1. Merge first: Did that
2. Use -f: I know enough not to do that.

I think I understand the concept of rebasing - which I don't think applies here, since I'm the only one who did anything in this commit tree. Of course I've pulled.

**So my question is:** How can I resolve this specific situation?

Also, recommendations for where to learn proper version control workflow would be nice. Everything I find tells me what the *commands* are, but I've failed to find clear instructions on *when* to use them.

I've added a picture of the project. Commit 147 was mine, and I could push it just fine. All oher commits are also made by me.

[image: Mercurial commit tree]

Comment: hg/Tortoise count the head of each named branch separately. You _are_ creating a new head on the "kjeld" branch, which is your close-branch commit. This is definitely a case where I would be ok with the use of `-f`.

Comment: @Edward So since I only push a new head on my *private* branch, it won't cause any problems? If so, care to post this as an answer?

Comment: I just expanded on the answer a bit. Leave a comment if you still have questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hg reports a "head" for every named branch. In your screenshot, you are needing to push rev 154, which is the head of your `kjeld` branch. It is an `outgoing` changeset because  you are pushing rev 155 and you must therefore push 155's entire history as well. Others will get that branch when they pull your changes and will have a head on their version of `kjeld` (note that it will most likely not be numbered 154 since those numbers are repo specific). You will be fine though since that head is a `close-branch` changeset so it will not appear in their default list for `hg heads` and `hg branches`.

One way to avoid your current issue is to use [bookmarks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Bookmarks) to temporarily note what that head represents e.g. `issue-45`, `big-feature-2`, etc. and only push when merged into mainline development.

For us, we set up a "private" repo for each dev on the server where they store/backup work in progress. It is expected that there are multiple heads, dead branches, and other gunk in these "private" repos. The `dev` repo, however, only ever has a single head and must pass the build and build tests.

---

In response to your comment about your "private" branch: When you push your `tip` you will also push your branch named `kjeld`. Others who want to work on that code must pull it to get the tip of your development. It will not be a "private" branch.